# How to use vimtutor?

Tags: vim, vimtutor

Someone recommended me that I should use `vimtutor` to learn the basics of `vim`. But I have no idea how to use it. Is it an application? A website?

[This is the only link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100107121743/http://linuxcommand.gds.tuwien.ac.at/man_pages/vimtutor1.html) that was given during the discussion here and I can't find a link to anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes, `vimtutor` is literally the name of a program that runs you through a tutorial for vim.  If installed on a Unix environment, that command should be sufficient.  On windows, there's an entry in the start menu folder just titled "Vim tutor" which is a shortcut for `vimtutor`

Comment: So I guess my question is, how do I even install it? There is no link on the website.

Comment: It comes with Vim.  If you've installed Vim successfully, you've installed `vimtutor` as well.

Comment: `:help vimtutor` describes a few tricks as well

Comment: On windows you can open the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\tutor\tutor (from   https://superuser.com/questions/270938/how-to-run-vimtutor-on-windows/271076#271076 )

Comment: Also when installing vim check the "Install .bat files" box to run it form powershell

Answer (score 10):

If you're using neovim, the way to enter in Tutor file directly from terminal is typing:

```
    nvim +Tutor
```

I've learned just reading the "nvim -h"

Answer (score 8):

vimtutor is a program that usually gets installed when you install the normal vim/gvim package.  You should be able to just run "vimtutor" on the command line, assuming that it got built and installed correctly, and is on your path, etc...  If you can't run it on the command line, or it doesn't work for you, you'll have to do some digging to figure out why.  In my experience vimtutor doesn't always work as expected.  I would start by looking in the install folder for Vim, and see what you can find.

At its core, it's basically just a text file that has some examples that walk you through the basic commands available in vim.  It shows you have to navigate using the keyboard, how to edit text, and use some other basic commands.  If you can't get vimtutor to work immediately, you can either just keep messing with it, do some more searching (there are plenty of results when you search for vimtutor in google) or just give up on it and learn vim using another type of tutorial.  Vimtutor is fairly limited anyway, so it's definitely not that important to get working.

Answer (score 2):

I have neovim (nvim) and executing `vimtutor` command from terminal doesn't launch the tutor.
If it's the case you can execute `nvim` first and inside the running editor execute `:Tutor` command which bring you to VIM Tutor.

Answer (score -5):

Type:

```
yum install vim
```

Even if you have VIM already installed.
This will install additional files including the "vimtutor".