# vim/gvim command line switches?

Tags: vim, gvim, command-line-arguments

I've just spent 1/2 hour trying to find a list of command line switches for vim.  Since vim is a "command line editor" a search on "vim command line ..." is not very useful.

I got curious trying to alter the tutor to use my brand new _vimrc file. Finally figured which of these lines in 'vimtutor.bat' to modify:

```
vim -u NONE -c "so $VIMRUNTIME/tutor/tutor.vim"
```

Removing the '-u NONE' gets it to do what I want.

Thanks to @Fannyxl for their answer to this question: [How to run vimtutor on windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/270938/how-to-run-vimtutor-on-windows) that showed me where to find the .bat file.  If I had enough rep in this community I'd thank them proper...

...and thanks to Heptite and my new rad vim skills:

```
--noplugin  Skip loading plugins.  Resets the 'loadplugins' option.
    {not in Vi}
    Note that the |-u| argument may also disable loading plugins:
        argument    load vimrc files    load plugins  
        (nothing)       yes         yes
        -u NONE         no          no
        -u NORC         no          yes
        --noplugin      yes         no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

```
:help vim-arguments
```

Or more specifically:

```
:help startup-options
```

Or on the command line, if you want to see a summary:

```
vim --help
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Where do I find the documentation for vim/gvim command line switches?

On Unix the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) command can be used to find out information about commands. It displays reference manual pages and can find reference pages by keyword.

To see the reference pages for `vim` type the following in your shell:

```
man vim
```

[VIM(1)](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/vim1.html) shows the output from this command. As you can see it documents all of the command line options.

Comment: Just a note that unixhelp.ed.ac.uk does not seem to be online anymore.

Comment: Am I the first to have the opinion that "man" sucks? It's like someone that just learned to swallow trying to drink from a firehose. We almost never need "all" the options. Just the 20% we use 80% of the time.